# Three.js setHSL() sets unexpected color

Tags: three.js

> **setHSL(h,s,l)** - set the value of this color on the supplied HSL values. The values range from 0 to 1.

why am I getting cyan when I try `material.color.setHSL( 0.5, 1, 0.5 )`? I expect to have yellow instead as color picker shows

[image]

```js
let camera, scene, renderer, material;

init();

function init() {

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.01, 10 );
    camera.position.z = 1;

    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    const geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry();
    material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xffffff } );
  material.color.setHSL( 0.5, 1, 0.5 );
    
    const mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
    scene.add( mesh );

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
}
```

```css
body {
   margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.rawgit.com/mrdoob/three.js/master/build/three.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: [`THREE.Color()`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/math/Color) accepts hsl-string, so `material.color.set("hsl(50, 100%, 50%)")` will work.

Comment: @prisoner849 I used method that accepts numeric because I need random lightness for same hue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Color picker goes from 0 to 360.
setHSL goes from 0 to 1.

if you want hue 50 out of 360 you set 50/360 which is 0.1388888888888889.

setHSL( 0.1388888888888889, 1, 0.5 ) is yellow.

```js
let camera, scene, renderer, material;

init();

function init() {

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.01, 10 );
    camera.position.z = 1;

    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    const geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry();
    material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xffffff } );
  material.color.setHSL( 0.1388888888888889, 1, 0.5 );
    
    const mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
    scene.add( mesh );

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
}
```

```css
body {
   margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.rawgit.com/mrdoob/three.js/master/build/three.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: oh, man, the best part is - If I'd need blue here this would never happen)) you're a lifesaver, thank you so much!